# Database with repeating records

Tags: android, sqlite

I have sqlite database in my app.When I have Internet connection,data is saved and when I haven't Internet connection,I loaded data from database and show that in ListView.But in this ListView I have many records,I think when I have Internet I created records how many times,how I start the app.But now how can I delete all records,create new,and dont create the same records every time when I start my app?
MainList:

```
public class MainList extends ListFragment{
    SqlHelper dbHelper;
    ListView mainList;
    ProgressBar progBar;
    private static String url = "https://fierce-citadel-4259.herokuapp.com/hamsters";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String IMAGE = "image";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> jsonlist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> bdList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragme, null);
        mainList = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    progBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        return v;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (isNetworkConnected()==true) {
            new ProgressTask().execute();
        }
        else{
            displaysavedlv();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id);
        String title = jsonlist1.get(position).get("title");
        String description= jsonlist1.get(position).get("description");
        String image = jsonlist1.get(position).get("image");


        MyDetailFragment detailFragment = new MyDetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if(isNetworkConnected()==true) {
            bundle.putString("title", title);
            bundle.putString("description", description);
            bundle.putString("image", image);
        }
        else
        {
            String dbtitle= bdList.get(position).get("title");
            String dbdescription = bdList.get(position).get("description");
            String dvimage = bdList.get(position).get("image");
            bundle.putString("title",dbtitle);
            bundle.putString("description",dbdescription);
            bundle.putString("image",dvimage);
        }
        detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentCont,detailFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private Activity activity;
        private MainActivity context;
        private String[] params;

        public ProgressTask(MainActivity activity) throws SQLException {
            this.activity = getActivity();
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        }

        public ProgressTask()  {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            try {
                dbHelper = new SqlHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            this.params = params;
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            for(int i =0;i<json.length();i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String vtitle = c.getString(TITLE);
                    String vdescription = c.getString(DESCRIPTION);
                    String vimage = c.getString(IMAGE);
                    dbHelper.open();
                    dbHelper.createEntry(vtitle, vimage, vdescription);
                    dbHelper.close();

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put(TITLE, vtitle);
                    map.put(DESCRIPTION, vdescription);
                    map.put(IMAGE, vimage);

                    jsonlist1.add(map);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success){

            if (isNetworkConnected()==true) {
                progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), jsonlist1, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TITLE, DESCRIPTION}, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.description});
                mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else {
                displaysavedlv();
            }
        }
    }

    private void displaysavedlv() {
        try {
            dbHelper = new SqlHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bdList = dbHelper.getAllData();

        CustomListAdapter adapter1 = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), bdList, R.id.list_item, new String[]{TITLE, DESCRIPTION}, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.description});
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }
    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
}
```

SqlHelper class:

```
public class SqlHelper {
    String title;
    String description;
    String image;
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private SqlHelper mDb;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBCategory";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "categoryTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    KEY_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    KEY_DESCRIPTION + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + KEY_IMAGE + TEXT_TYPE +

                    " )";
    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public SqlHelper(Context c) throws SQLException {
        ourContext = c;
        try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public SqlHelper open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                            KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public long createEntry(String title, String description,String image) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION,description);
        cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);

        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllData()
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from categoryTable", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){

            HashMap<String,String>  hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashmap.put("title", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE)));
            hashmap.put("description", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGE)));
            hashmap.put("image", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESCRIPTION)));




            array_list.add(hashmap);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement sync functionality, you can include isSaved flag in your database to mark the field already saved and so you won't write that data again into your database, rather only unsaved data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I understand from you, every time when you have a connection you put all the data in your  database to show them later if the there is no connection 
but after while your database contains many data, so you want to only to show the last data you retrieved , Basically the answer is   before you put the new data in the database make sure to delete everything in your database by creating a drop table or delete method query .. then you are good to go.

Comment: how can I delete my recods?
I create method "deleteall":
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete("categoryTable",null,null);
db.close();
and put this into onPreExecute.Its right?

Comment: yes, but make sure that you a connection before deleting